# What video formats can be played from a Flex app?

Tags: apache-flex

The only video playback control I can see in Flex is mx.controls.VideoDisplay, which appears to support .FLV only. Is that correct? Are there other ways to play video in a Flex app, and do they require anything on the server side or can you just point at a hosted video file, and Flex takes care of streaming/buffering?

Also, if you put 2 VideoDisplay controls on top of each other, could you see one video superimposed on another?

Edit: I forgot to say, of course all the Flash controls are available in a Flex app as well as the Flex ones. So if those provide greater abilities they are of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Flash / Flex can play flv, f4v, and H264 files starting with flash player 9 update 3.

Heres a tutorial on video in flash with an alpha chanel: http://theflashblog.com/?p=59

spec: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flv/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's the green-screen effect I am specifically interested in... I thought if the videos encoded an alpha channel then the top one could be overlayed on top of the bottom one without a lot of messing about.

Is it really possible to mix 2 videos frame-by-frame using custom AS3 code? It sounds fairly expensive on the CPU and Flex is not hugely quick for raw processing.